# C# ASPX Web service that supports Mobile Apps

Tags: c#, android, iphone, asp.net, mobile

I'm starting to build a web site which will use jquery on the client site and ajax call to an aspx handler or a web service. 
The question is which architecture will allow me to use the same services on a mobile app which will be developed later on IPhone or Android.

Answer (score 1):

I would say as long as your api returns xml or json you will be able to consume it on any platform, including iOS and Android.

Check out the new [Web API framework](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for .net which provides a really nice way of building HTTP services.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) can do all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to communicate with web services that are written in asp.net / C# from either an Android or an IPhone.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://url.com")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] // or ResponseFormat.Xml
    public ResponseObject MyWebMethod(RequestObject input)
    {
        ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
        // Do some stuff
        return response;
    }
}
```

One note, you'll want to make sure that your request/response objects are marked as `[Serializable]` in your code.